# Variance of the mean for difference between independent random variables

Tags: expected-value, variance

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. I draw $N_x$ samples from $X$ and $N_y$ samples from $Y$. I am interested in finding the expected values for $X$, $Y$ and $Z = X-Y$. In order to find the last one, I will do the following. I will consider every possible pair of the samples from $X$ and $Y$, there will be $N_z = N_x N_y$ of those. For each of those pairs, I will find the difference between $X$ and $Y$, and then use that data to estimate the expected value of $Z$.

The variance of the mean is the variance of the sample, divided by the number of observations

$$\bar{\sigma}^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{N}$$

Does this mean that asymptotically, with increasing $N$, my estimates for the expected value of $Z$ are significantly more precise than those of $X$ and $Y$? Or am I cheating by creating extra samples out of thin air. If I indeed am, what is the correct number of samples to be used for estimating the variance of the mean of $Z$ obtained via such procedure?

Comment: I suggest you work through an example in the case (say) where your $N_x$ and $N_y$ are small, such as $N_x=2,N_y=3$. Both ways, to see the naive standard estimator, and your new suggested variant.

Comment: @kimchilover what is the naive standard estimator in this case?

Comment: Ok I did some simulations, and it appears that the variance of the mean of Z does not decrease faster than those of X and Y. But it still remains to understand why

Comment: By naive estimate I meant the average of the $X$ numbers minus the average of the $Y$ numbers.  How does that estimate compare with your $Z$ number?

Comment: @kimchilover Ah yes, I wonder how I missed that :D. I'll give it a try

Comment: @kimchilover Ok I just answered my own question. They are exactly the same, it is not too hard to show mathematically. The conclusion is that the points produced by the pairwise procedure are not independent, which invalidates the calculation of the variance of the mean. Thanks a lot for your help. I will likely delete the question